# Extracting the point mass measure of some type of positive measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let us consider the measure algebra $M(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all Radon measures on the reals.
Let  $\delta_0$ be the point mass measure concentrated on 0,  which is also the multiplicative identity of $M(\mathbb{R})$.

> Q. Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure in  $M(\mathbb{R})$. Do there exist a strictly positive real number $r>0$ and Radon measures  $\mu_1,\dots, \mu_n$ satisfying the following identity? $$\mu^**\mu+\sum_1^n\mu_i^**\mu_i=r\delta_0.$$

Remark. $M(\mathbb{R})=C_0(\mathbb{R})^*$ is a unital dual Banach $*$-algebra. The involution on $M(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as follows:
$$\langle \mu^*,f\rangle=\int f(t)\overline{d\mu(-t)}.$$

Comment: @
Onur Oktay, I did not get what you mean!

Comment: You might want to use the Bochner's characterization of positive measures.

Comment: More details or a reference please.

Comment: It's perhaps easier to solve the equation on the Fourier transform side. However, you need to make sure that the solutions on the Fourier side indeed correspond to Fourier transforms of measures. Bochner's theorem may come in handy for this, e.g., https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel or you may just search Bochner's theorem in Harmonic analysis books.